# How to force linux interface to work with specific network card

Tags: networking, hardware, debian-wheezy

It's my first time expercience with multiples networks cards.
I have two networks cards on my debian server.

- card 1:  on on a public network,
- card 2 : on private network

I have edit my /etc/network/interface file with :

- eth0 : use dhcp (public network)
- eth1 : use static IP (private network)
  my interface are up using allow-hotplug

But in fact, eth0 is automaticly attached to the card2 and eth1 to the card1.

I have changed my interface file ( invert eth0 and eth1 conf) but it's not work, i think the cards are randomly attached to interfaces.

*How can i configure my cards/interface to force eth0 use only card1 and eth1 use only card2 ?*

Thanks for your help.

Sorry for my lack of english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to configure udev mappings for your network cards based on their MAC addresses.

Good explanations are provided at [debianhelp on udev](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/udev.htm)

Comment: Thanks for this link, i have add a rules file for rename device ( but this link is not good for debian : SYSFS{address} must be replaced by ATTR{address}. Now it's work perfectly.